# Как рассплитить строку по двум условиям с помощью регулярного выражения?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

Мне нужно сплитить строку по пробелу или запятой. Вот как я это делаю:
`string.split(/(?:,|\s)+/)`
Как сделать так, чтобы строка не сплитилась по пробелу, если он находится в подстроке, которая внутри квадратных скобок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, ваше регулярное выражение лучше записать в виде символьного класса, `/[\s,]+/`, так оно будет работать быстрее.

Чтобы строка не разбивалась пробелами и запятыми внутри квадратных скобок, можно использовать

```js
console.log("[abc def, ghi] jkl mno, prst".split(/[\s,]+(?![^\][]*])/));
console.log("[abc def, ghi] jkl mno, prst".match(/\[[^\][]*]|[^\s,]+/g));
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения №1](https://regex101.com/r/dmj4Ty/2) и [пример работы регулярного выражения №2](https://regex101.com/r/dmj4Ty/1).

Для большей точности работы первого выражения добавьте блок предварительного просмотра назад, `/(?<!\[[^\][]*)[\s,]+(?![^\][]*])/` (см. [пример](https://regex101.com/r/dmj4Ty/3)).

**Описание шаблонов**

- `(?<!\[[^\][]*)` - отицательный блок предварительного просмотра назад, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу перед текущей позицией есть символ `[`, за которым следует 0 и более символов, отличных от `[` и `]`
- `[\s,]+` - один и более пробельных символов или/и запятых
- `(?![^\][]*])` - отицательный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции есть 0 и более символов, отличных от `[` и `]`, а потом `]`

Второе регулярное выражение (используемое в `String#match`):

- `\[[^\][]*]` - `[`, затем 0 и более символов, отличных от `[` и `]`, а затем `]`
- `|` - или
- `[^\s,]+` - один и более символов, отличных от пробельных символов и запятых.